# What is the difference of cutoff frequency to -3dB frequency in an active filter?

Tags: operational-amplifier, active-filter

This table shows the K values of a particular Q value on a Sallen-Key active filter:
[image]

Why is the \$K_c\$ value **(cutoff value)** different from \$K_3\$ value **(-3dB value)** on all Q's (except 0.707 which is a butterworth approx) ?

I mean, isn't the cutoff frequency pertains to the -3dB frequency? What is the difference of a **cutoff frequency** to **-3dB frequency**?

Answer (score 3):

> I mean, isn't the cutoff frequency pertains to the -3dB frequency?

To some degree you are correct, but this article points out that simple rules do not apply to under-dampening (peaking) or over-dampening, they will make those 2 values not equal.

This is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutoff_frequency)

> In electronics, cutoff frequency or corner frequency is the frequency
> either above or below which the power output of a circuit, such as a
> line, amplifier, or electronic filter has fallen to a given proportion
> of the power in the passband. Most frequently this proportion is one
> half the passband power, also referred to as the 3 dB point since a
> fall of 3 dB corresponds approximately to half power. As a voltage
> ratio this is a fall to \${\displaystyle \scriptstyle {\sqrt {1/2}}\
> > \approx \ 0.707}\scriptstyle\$ of the
> passband voltage. Other ratios besides the 3 dB point may also be
> relevant.

> **Chebyshev filters**
>
> **Sometimes other ratios are more convenient than the 3 dB point**. For
> instance, in the case of the Chebyshev filter it is usual to define
> the cutoff frequency as the point after the last peak in the frequency
> response at which the level has fallen to the design value of the
> passband ripple. The amount of ripple in this class of filter can be
> set by the designer to any desired value, hence the ratio used could
> be any value.

Comment: Quote:...."simple rules do not apply to non-linear filters..". Chebyshev and other "non-Butterworth" functions are, of course, linear. Non-linearity has nothing to do with the proble under discussion.

Comment: @LvW Fixed the nonlinear bug. Thx

Comment: You could generalize that, usually, the 3 dB cutoff (or the inflexion point of the phase) applies to: Gaussian, Bessel, Butterworth, transitional, Halpern, Papoulis, inverse Pascal, inverse Chebyshev, or any other filter that has a monotonically non-increasing passband, unless stated otherwise. I mention this because too often there seem to be over-simplifications as if Butterworth and Chebyshev are the only two types of filters.

Comment: Yes - good comment. More than this, for Bessel responses, often the passband is defined in the time domain (group delay) rather than frequency domain.